# Le « soulier en cuir pour homme avec le talon et sans lacets » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, habillement

Je regarde le premier soulier à gauche dans [cet article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip-on_shoe) et je me demande si j'ai le vocabulaire pour le nommer et le décrire précisément. Je pars avec comme lexique *souliers en cuir pour homme*, *habillés* et « loafers »<sup>1</sup>, mais c'est normalement avec un talon et sans lacets (et tu peux glisser longtemps sur un plancher bien ciré avec ça). Les gens disent quoi ?

[image]
<sub><sub>Attribution : Goodreg3, CC BY-SA 4.0 sur [Wikipédia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:British_boys_school_shoes.jpg) (taille réduite)</sub></sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Jeune, je disais systématiquement [*loafers*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loafer) mais je n'en connaissais pas l'orthographe, que je viens d'apprendre il y a cinq minutes en échouant initialement à retrouver le mot au dictionnaire anglais ; je pensais que c'était <strike>*low-fur*</strike>, étrange mélange sur *fur-lined* ou je ne sais trop.</sub>

Comment: Tout qualificatif, adjectif ou participe, placé en tête d'une phrase, doit se rapporter clairement et sans équivoque au sujet de la phrase (http://www.cosmovisions.com/adjectif.htm). « Clairement », oui, mais « sans équivoque »,je crois que non. « Quand jeune » ? « Parce que jeune » ? Je vous laisse voir.

Answer (score 2):

Ces souliers sont du style que l'on appelle "mocassin". Il y en a de toutes sortes, de la gamme « chaussure courantes » à la gamme « chaussure de ville ». ([chaussures de ville](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chaussures+de+ville&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchaussures%20de%20ville%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

[Chaussures type mocassin](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=mocassin&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY1fTZ19_sAhVRTxUIHZHfBqAQjJkEegQIEBAB&biw=1056&bih=553)

Sans crainte d'être incompris vous pouvez utiliser les termes suivants.

- **mocassins** (*courant, en particulier lorsque l'on sait de quelle sorte il s'agit. Autrement, il faut préciser le type de soulier dont il est question.*)
- **chaussures/souliers style mocassin** (*Pour plus de précision il faudra dire par exemple « des chaussures habillées » ([réf.](https://www.asos.com/fr/homme/chaussures-bottes-baskets/chaussures-habillees/cat/?cid=5773)), qui est un terme très courant.*)
- **chaussures habillées, style mocassin** (*Cette combinaison sera comprise sans ambiguïté, mais ce n'est pas nécessairement un terme que vous entendrez souvent.*)

En ce qui concerne les souliers qui ne font pas partie de ce qui est appelé le style habillé, des termes possibles sont **souliers/chaussures de tous les jours** ou **chaussures courantes**. ([habillement courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=habillement+courant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chabillement%20courant%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chabillement%20courant%3B%2Cc0))

*Exemple* (user LPH)

- Il portait des chaussures de ville style mocassin qu'il n'avait encore jamais mises.

Comment: Merci. Donc on dit que l'on dit « je vais m'acheter des souliers de style mocassin » ou "de la gamme « chaussure courantes »" ou  « chaussure de ville ». Svp présenter une phrase complète avec la formulation privilégiée exacte que l'on trouve la plus courante, incluant toute ponctuation pertinente.

Comment: @ilsuffit Je ne peux pas affirmer que les termes que j'utilise soient les plus courants ; ce que je peux dire c'est qu'ils seront compris. Néanmoins, je vais essayer de collecter des exemples.

Comment: @ilsuffit Je ne trouve pas d'exemples mais j'ai ajouté quelques termes qui bien que pas vérifiables en tant que combinaisons sont justifiables selon le sens des mots.

Comment: @ilsuffit « Je vais m'acheter des souliers de style mocassin. » va bien. « Je vais m'acheter des mocassin de gamme « chaussure courantes» » ne sera peut-être pas compris par des personnes peu initiées au vocabulaire de l'habillement. Ça peut aller dans un contexte particulier, par exemple, pour ajouter une précision si quelqu'un fait une remarque. (— Tu vas t'acheter de beau souliers, alors ? — Mais non ! Qu'est-ce que tu vas chercher ? Je vais m'acheter des souliers de gamme courante, des chaussures de tous les jours, pour aller à l'usine.) Remarquer la répétition dans l'exemple.

Comment: Merci ! Le "style mocassin" me dérange probablement parce que je vois une différence entre (1-4, 6) et 5 dans vos images, et que c'est vraiment 5 que je recherche. Mais un mocassin et une chaussure au style mocassin ne sont peut-être pas la même chose. Je n'ai aucune difficulté à décrire le soulier mais je veux raffiner mon vocabulaire et savoir ce qu'on dit spontanément.

Comment: Si tu es intéressé par ce qui se dit spontanément, commence par éviter *souliers* et utiliser *chaussures* à la place. Mes enfants se moquent de moi quand je dit *souliers* en disant que "c'est un mot de vieux"....

Comment: @jlliagre Ce doit être une réaction dans le cadre de la  théorie de la nouvelle société : pour la victoire finale du modernisme on doit passer par la dictature de la jeunesse. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=souliers%2C+chaussures&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csouliers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchaussures%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csouliers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchaussures%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ce n'est pas une dictature, juste une évolution naturelle. Les modes changent...

Comment: @jlliagre Probablement que je suis attaché à _souliers de course_. Je dis peu souvent _chaussures_, je le sens comme plus formel ou c'est que je suis plus vieux ou le penchant pour les plus vieux mots est [régional](https://youtu.be/38TCiITH8Qk) chez moi.